# Converting coordinate representation to adjecency list representation

Tags: python, graph, awk

What is the most efficient way to convert this file:

```
10 3
10 5
12 6
12 19
19 12 
19 14 
19 10
```

to this:

```
10 3 5
12 6 19
19 12 14 10
```

First column of the input file is numerically sorted in increasing order.

Any solutions using Python, AWK, etc. are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import groupby
lines, op_file = [line.split() for line in open("In.txt")], open("Out.txt", "w")
for key, grp in groupby(lines, key = lambda x: x[0]):
    print >> op_file, "{} {}".format(key, " ".join([i[1] for i in grp]))
op_file.close()
```

**Output**

```
10 3 5
12 6 19
19 12 14 10
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned awk:

```
$ awk '{a[$1]=a[$1]" "$2}END{for (i in a){print i a[i]}}' input
19 12 14 10
10 3 5
12 6 19
```

pipe it to `sort` to have it, well, sorted:

```
$ awk '...' input | sort
10 3 5
12 6 19
19 12 14 10
```

Comment: +1, awk rocks! The sort needs a `-n`, though, right?

Comment: `-n` never hurts since we are comparing numbers

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2:

```
import itertools, operator

with open(infilename) as infile:
    input = (line.split() for line in infile)
    output = itertools.groupby(input, operator.itemgetter(0))
    with open(outfilename, 'w') as outfile:
        for key, line in output:
            print >>outfile, key, ' '.join(val[1] for val in line)
```

This assumes that the input and output files are different: you could just write the output to standard out and leave it as the user's problem to save it.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this code

```
fp = open('/tmp/test.txt')

list_dict = {}

for line in fp.readlines():
    split_values = line.split()
    if split_values[0] in list_dict:
        list_dict[split_values[0]].extend(split_values[1:])
    else:
        list_dict[split_values[0]] = split_values

for val in  list_dict.values():
    print " ".join(val)
```